# How to invoke a Java method that is in a Array of Strings? (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException)

Tags: java, arrays, string, invoke

I have an `Array` of `Strings` with `Method names` which I am trying to invoke in a loop. I've retrieved the names of all variables in the class and added the required text to fill the whole function and added the whole string into the list:

```
String[] methodNames= new String[16];
Class c = telegramm.class;
Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

int x=0;
for (Field field : fields) 
{               
    String str = field.getName();
    String variableName = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    // This is how I initially intended to call the method
    // methodNames[x] = "set" + variableName + "(parts[" + x + "]);";

    // but with the method I found I used this
    methodNames[x] = "set" + variableName";

    Method gs1Method = tClass.getMethod("getString1", new Class[] {});
    //String str1 = (String) gs1Method.invoke(t, new Object[] {});
    //System.out.println("getString1 returned: " + str1);
    x++;
}
```

So with this I add a method call String into the array `methodNames`.

And I've found a way to invoke methods:

```
Method gs1Method = tClass.getMethod("getString1", new Class[] {});
String str1 = (String) gs1Method.invoke(t, new Object[] {});
System.out.println("getString1 returned: " + str1);
```

Which works, but ONLY when you hardcode the name of the method ("getString1").

Now I would like to implement a way to call these functions via the `methodNames` array.

When I pass an object of methodNames array as a parameter:

```
getMethod(methodNames[x], new Class[] {});
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
kin.gateway.adient.Testing.setBoolean1(java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
at kin.gateway.adient.ClassMethodTest.main(ClassMethodTest.java:31)
```

I also tried to add the string to a singular variable `String variableName = "set" + variableName;` but got the same result.

Why won't it accept a String as a variable?

Comment: `setBoolean1(java.lang.String)` maybe you should pass a boolean instead of a string. normally `setBoolean` methods, require a boolean value as parameter

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand this correctly, I should pass a boolean value as a method name parameter or ... ?

Comment: currently you call the method `setBoolean1` with a string as parameter. this means that it would require a method signature like this: `setBoolean1(String value)`. normally, you have the signature like this: `setBooelan1(boolean value)`. so you simply have to change the value that you call the method with from `String` to `Boolean`. or you change the method signature of the clas to accept strings instead of boolean values

Comment: yes that was part of the solution... sorry I'm new to Java and am not used to read the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample should helps you to find the error, after you can add a loop on it according the methods you have :

1 - Your Telegramm class :

```
public class Telegramm {

    String value1;
    String value2;

    public String getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value) {
        this.value1 = value;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return this.value2;
    }

    public String setValue2(String value) {
        this.value2 = value;
        return this.value2;
    }

}
```

2 - Invocation of the methods : getValue1() and setValue2()

```
try {
            // Create our Telegramm instance
            Telegramm telegramm = new Telegramm();
            telegramm.setValue1("value1");
            telegramm.setValue2("value2");

            // Invoke public static String getValue1()
            Method getValue1Method = telegramm.getClass().getMethod("getValue1", null);
            String result = (String)getValue1Method.invoke(telegramm);
            System.out.println("result invocation getValue1() : " + result);

            // Invoke public static String setValue2()
            getValue1Method = telegramm.getClass().getMethod("setValue2", new Class[] {String.class});
            result = (String)getValue1Method.invoke(telegramm, "ValueX");
            System.out.println("result invocation setValue2() : " + result);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to solve it myself. I'll still mark this as a solution. Cheers